# Search if all string in .txt

Tags: python, if-statement, string-search

I am trying to run a program to look at a .txt file and if, else depending on the content

I thought would be

```
Searhterms = [A, B]
with('output.txt') as f:

    if ('A' and 'B') in f.read():
        print('mix')
    eLif ('A') in f.read:
        if ('B') not in f.read:
            print('ONLY A')
    elif ('B') in f.read():
        if ('A') not in f.read:
            print('ONLY B') 
    else:
        if ('A' and 'B') not in f.read:
            print('NO AB)
```

But if A and B present it works, but if only one it skips to the else. I am getting more confused about the longer I look at this.

Comment: f.read() empties the first time you use it.

Comment: Can you suggest any alternative methods?

Comment: You could put what you read in a variable and check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd better use this:

```
Searhterms = [A, B]  # not sure why you need this

with('output.txt') as fin :  # nice name for the INPUT file, btw
    lines = fin.readlines()

for line in lines :
    if ('A' in line) and ('B' in line):
        print('mix')
    eLif 'A' in line:  # nice uppercase 'L', will puzzle the python
        #if 'B' not in line:    # don't need this
        print('ONLY A')
    elif 'B' in line:
        #if 'A' not in line:    # don't need this
        print('ONLY B') 
    else:
        #if ('A' and 'B') not in f.read:   # this condition is not required
        print('NO AB')

if len(lines) == 0 :
    print('empty file')
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but one issue. If my output.txt file is empty it does not print 'NO AB' but if it has a random number in it it does. is there a way to get it to printout if the output.txt is empty?

Comment: Works perfectly! You're a star

Comment: Sorry! Thought it was all fixed. If file is empty, prints 'empty file' but if its not now prints Mix empty file it is sticking empty file on the end of everything

Comment: @Smellegg fixed that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, `f.read()` reads all the content of your file in one go, so subsequent calls to `f.read()` return no data. You need to store the data in a variable. Also, you misunderstood how `and` operator works.

```
with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    if 'A' in data and 'B' in data:
        print('mix')
    elif 'A' in data:
        print('ONLY A')
    elif 'B' in data:
        print('ONLY B') 
    else:
        print('NO AB)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Zabir Al Nazi here.
the read f.read() empties the file

use this

```
Searhterms = ['A', 'B']

with open('output.txt') as f:
    content = f.read()
    if ('A' and 'B') in content:
        print('mix')
    elif 'A' in content:
        if 'B' not in content:
            print('ONLY A')
    elif 'B' in content:
        if 'A' not in content:
            print('ONLY B')
    else:
        if ('A' and 'B') not in content:
            print('NO AB')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is little buggy.
First, you should call `f.read()` only once. 
And your if statements are wrong constructed.

Try this code and analyze it:

```
with open('output.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read()

if 'A' in lines and 'B' in lines:
    print('mix')
elif 'A' in lines:
    print('ONLY A')
elif 'B' in lines:
    print('ONLY B')
else:
    print('NO AB')
```